# Allow users to upload only supported video and audio formats

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-upload

I am building a file uploader in a React app, and I want to make sure all user uploads can be played by modern browsers and devices. For audio and video, should it only accept mp3 and mp4 respectively? That's what it would seem, according to MDN. Or do most uploaders accept more filetypes and just convert them? Can't decide how to do this the "right" way.

EDIT: Another challenge is that from mobile devices, a lot of people will be wanting to upload from camera roll or Voice Memo etc. (This is an artist portfolio / social networking app). So what does Twitter and Facebook do? Accept .m4a and convert it? I can figure something out on my own but the reason I ask is ---> maybe some of you have done this and will have a more helpful answer

Comment: For smaller scale applications just restrict what format can be uploaded, unless, of course you are trying to make an online converter tool

Comment: Yes, but restrict to which formats? I think a lot of folks will be uploading from their phone ... I might need to convert a wider array of files to websafe formats.

Comment: there are many API's to convert video's online like [cloudconvert.com/api](https://cloudconvert.com/api) or [developers.zamzar.com](https://developers.zamzar.com/)